# Why does Tomcat allow Apps with same path?

Tags: java, tomcat

Why does Tomcat allow 2 or more apps to have same path

```
         **Path**    **Version**
App1:   /proxy       1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
App2:   /proxy       2.0.0-SNAPSHOT
```

As you see the apps have same path but just different version.
So if I make a request to /proxy interestingly it works. But which app actually serves my request ?
For me this is a really dangerous behaviour from Tomcat . if you use tomcat's REST Api and you do not know there is alreay some other app with older version installed , your users could be directed to the old version. Really bad. And especially I do not think Tomcat is used for scaling here like a Kubernetes :)

Comment: This is called the [parallel deployment](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/config/context.html#Parallel_deployment) feature. If you have two different apps, you should use different context paths.

Comment: Ok. But as I mentioned it is about the version !! This is normal that you upgrade the version of your app regularly

Comment: If two versions of the same app are deployed, new clients connect to the newest version, while clients that already have a session open, connect to the app that created the session. With a REST API the second case does not occur.